# The right way to show a child's state in parent's DOM

Tags: reactjs, flux

Consider having a child component like this:

```
class ChildCmp extends React.Component
{
    constructor() {
        this.state = { title: 'Child Component', data: 'Some data' };
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>{this.state.data}</div>);
    }
}
```

In my scenario, I could have a different types of child components like mentioned above. And I've also got the following parent component:

```
class ParentCmp extends React.Component
{
    constructor() {
        this.state = { childCmps: [(<ChildCmp />)] };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.childCmps.map(function(cmp) {
                    return (
                        <span>Title: ...
                            {cmp}
                        </span>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I would like to get the child component's title out of its inner state and show it in the parent's DOM. I know I can just show the title in the child's itself DOM but that way I have to design a global frame within each different kind of child redundantly. I would rather not do that!

How can I access a child's inner state from its parent?

Comment: you would use refs here... https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html

Comment: Is the `title` and `data` actually stateful? In your example they are just static properties and don't need to be part of state. Also, you [should not put rendered components in state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll post another question in that regard. But here, they are supposed to be changed over the time and the parent component should get notified of their changes.

Comment: In that case you want to use a callback. Pass the callback to the child through props, and invoke it whenever the state changes. In this case you can also remove the state altogether from the child and just invoke the callback with changed state, the parent sets state on itself, and passes the new state back to the child through props.